# Lingon open source version for editing launchd on Leopard (10.5)?

Tags: launchd, ui, macos

I'm looking for a free GUI app to help run programs on a schedule.  It seems that launchd is the underlying tool to use, and in the past Lingon has been recommended as a good GUI interface to launchd.

But now it seems that the open source (Apache License V2.0) version of Lingon 1.2.1 doesn't work on Leopard (10.5), and the newest version of Lingon (2.2.1) requires Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.6 or later and is no longer open source.

Has anyone gotten a version of Lingon to run on Leopard (10.5)?

Or is there another free alternative?

**Update** - thanks to Mark I found and tried 2.1.1 which seems to work.  But it requires a restart or logout when making a change - is that always needed for launchd?  Or just for Lingon?  If so, cron with the cronnix GUI seems like it would be much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/Lingon/) has all the previous versions.

Comment: I've tried 1.2.1 but it didn't work on leopard.  Are you aware of any that do?

Comment: Ahh - seems like 2.1.1 at the link you gave is working on Leopard - thanks!  But it says that when I make a change I have to reboot or log out.  Really???  Is that generally necessary for launchd, or specific to lingon?

Comment: You can load and unload the affected commands to test them and launchd treats them as if they loaded at reboot. Perhaps the wording was reminding you that the system level and user level items are not automatically loaded - you have to do that with a boot/log or by hand. It's simpler for most people that need Lingon to not use command line.